# How to remove font information at the head of page 1?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I set TeXLive 2011 on my MacBookPro. In my preamble I have:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}
\newfontfamily{\sbl}[Script=Hebrew]{SBL Hebrew}
```

When I compile with xelatex I get at the head of the first page:

```
"20
.otf,.ttf,.OTF,.TTF,.ttc,.TTC,.dfont
fontspec-preparse-externalScale=MatchLowercase,fontspec-preparse Hoefler Text
```

and the same for the font SBL Hebrew.

When I change the main font, for instance with Linux Libertine, I have a lot of informations on this font. The informations occupy almost the half of the page with Linux Libertine.
It is only on page 2 that the title of the article and my name appear.

How can I do to remove these ugly and unnecessary informations?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, not just a fraction of your preamble. The issue might be caused by something before these lines.

Comment: I complete my preamble:

Comment: I complete my preamble:

Comment: You can edit your original question using the 'edit' link just below it. No need to post it as a comment.

Comment: No further information: as it stands 'Not A Real Question'.